# Create new Docker image if a file is changed

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I would like to write Dockerfile that checks content of a (configuration) file and if the file was changed then Docker creates a new image.

Best practices how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you write your file like

```
COPY package.json ./package.json

RUN npm install
```

It should rebuild image each time you change package.json and run the build command

Comment: Well, that was simple. :-) Thanks! The FROM command was not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

This typically should go as part of your CI/CD Pipeline. Everytime you change a file you can trigger a ci build where you can configure creation of new docker image.

Comment: The file I was talking about is package.json used by NodeJS. If I change the package.json I want to create a new Docker image with packages mentioned in package.json. I am not quite sure how to integrate it with CI/CD.

Comment: Everytime you change package.json and push to repo, npm install should be run through any CI tool like Jenkins and after that you can create a new docker image from that.
Check the below:

https://dzone.com/articles/create-a-continuous-deployment-pipeline-with-nodej